# Spring Security. Special differences - accountNonExpired vs credentialsNonExpired vs accountNonLocked

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

**UserDetails** has three parameters **accountNonExpired**, **credentialsNonExpired**, and **accountNonLocked**.

I don't quite understand their differences in action. All three parameters block the account if set to false.

So why are they needed, if they perform the same action, I do not quite understand. After all, you can leave one parameter, for example, **accountNonLocked**, and that will be enough.

**Explain to me please, otherwise I don't understand something.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just separate set of reasons to block an account. Each of parameters has it's own exception:

```
accountNonLocked | LockedException
credentialsNonExpired | CredentialsExpiredException
accountNonExpired | AccountExpiredException
```

If you write your own exception handler, you could easily customize error messages/code logic. For example:

```
    @PostMapping("/login")
    public String login() {
        try{
            loginService.login();
            return "redirect:/main-page";
        }
        catch (CredentialsExpiredException e) {
            return "redirect:/change-credentials-page";
        }
        catch (LockedException e) {
            return "redirect:/write-to-admin-page";
        }
         ... etc
    }
```

Note: this is probably not a proper way to handle auth exceptions nor a good way to handle login logic